# Deeper proof of common expected value of random convex weights

Tags: expected-value, exchangeability

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$Let a finite collection of *exchangeable* random variables $X_1,...X_n$ (some authors would call this collection "interchangeable" since it is finite, reserving "exchangeable" for infinite collections). Exchangeability permits non-independence, as long as the form of dependence is such that any permutation of the index results in the same joint distribution. In any case the variables are marginally identically distributed. Expected values to appear are assumed to exist and be finite.

Set $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and consider the expected value

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \E\left( \frac{X_i}{S_n}\right)$$

By linearity of the expected value and the finiteness of the sum we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \E\left( \frac{X_i}{S_n}\right) = \E\left(\sum_{i=1}^n  \frac{X_i}{S_n}\right) = \E\left(\frac{S_n}{S_n}\right) = \E(1) = 1  \tag{1}$$

By exchangeability we have

$$\E\left( \frac{X_i}{S_n}\right) = \E\left( \frac{X_j}{S_n}\right) =: \E\left( \frac{X}{S_n}\right),\;\;\; i \neq j \tag{2}$$

Therefore

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \E\left( \frac{X_i}{S_n}\right) = n\E\left( \frac{X}{S_n} \right)\tag{3}$$

Combining

$$(1),(3) \implies \E\left( \frac{X}{S_n}\right) = \frac 1n \tag{4}$$

Seems obvious, right? Only, we would arrive at the same result if we had performed

$$ \E\left( \frac{X_i}{S_n}\right) = \frac{\E(X_i)}{\E(S_n)} = \frac{\E(X)}{n\E(X)} = \frac 1n  \tag{5}$$

*But*, this last operation, is not, in general, valid, and for *two* reasons: first because the numerator is not independent of the denominator. Second, because by Jensen's Inequality, the expected value of the reciprocal is not equal to the reciprocal of the expected value. Namely, if the numerator was independent of the denominator we could write $\E\left(\frac{Y}{Z}\right) = \E(Y)\cdot \E(1/Z)$, but still, $\E(1/Z) \neq 1/\E(Z)$.

**So, is there a "deeper" way to prove that nevertheless, in the case presented above, we can "distribute" the expected value operation in a way that we usually cannot?**

By "deeper" I imagine something that goes beyond my kindergarten arithmetic above.

Comment: In what sense do you mean "deeper"?

Comment: @whuber Well, something that starts at a more fundamental level than at the "expected-value-as-a-linear-operator" one. Measure-theoretic, convolution, joint distributions, characteristic functions...

Comment: Despite its superficial superficiality, linearity is very deep.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone As an economist, I second your comment.  I just wonder whether there exists  a proof employing more "technical" gadgets. Sometimes they have their uses.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what "the result" is?  What do you want to assume and what do you want to conclude in general? For instance, are you perhaps asking for the most general possible conditions on the bivariate distribution of $(X,S)$ that will assure $E(X/S)=E(X)/E(S)$, or do you want to focus on the exchangeable setting you have described?

Comment: @whuber Focusing on the exchangeability setting I guess is more concrete, but I admit I have a love for more and more general results. In fact, if we can have the result while dispensing with exchangeability, it would greatly enhance my understanding (but that's just me of course).